# Bootstrap add padding to select option

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was just wondering if it's possible to add padding to the select options in select dropdowns in the Twitter Boostrap framework. I've added padding to all my other inputs so the padding on my select options is out of line. I would expect something like...

```
option {
    padding: 0 24px;
}
```

... to do the trick but this does nothing to a bootstrap select option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Here's the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbmw3egx/

Comment: Could you set up a JSFiddle example? "The select option" doesn't ring a bell with me.

Comment: check your dev console, it's possible that the style is being overwritten somewhere. having option{some css} is valid so something else must be effecting it. where are you putting your css?

Comment: You cannot style the default `option` element as you are looking to, you will likely need to do a more full replacement of the `select` component

Comment: @Rvervuurt I've added a JS Fiddle for you to view

Comment: @atmd thanks but I've tried that - my style is definitely in place - it's just not doing anything!

Comment: No your right, very odd, when I did a fiddle with just the option css is worked. not come accross this before

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get the text in the `select` to be adjusted to the left by setting the `text-indent` property:

```
 select.form-control {
    text-indent: 16px;
 }
```

A bit more about the `text-indent` property here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp

Hope that helps!

Edit: It looks like Chrome/Safari uses `text-indent`, Firefox uses `text-indent` and `padding-left`, and IE makes use of `padding-left` for `select`. I'm not sure how you would specify the CSS to make it consistent across all of these browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the Bootstrap `form-control`, this first option displayed will take on the style of the `form-control` CSS class. So you'd need to override `form-control` too.

```
option {
    padding: 0 24px;
}

select.form-control {
    padding: 0 24px;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/dCJM6I7z5V

Comment: Hi Skelly. Unfortunately this one doesn't impact the select options in the same way my example doesn't.

Comment: What example? Did you post one?

Comment: Yeah I posted a code example. I've added a JS Fiddle now so you can hopefully see the problem. I'm looking at this in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, padding on select and input always appear differently. This is not a Bootstrap issue. You just need to adjust the padding on the select accordingly. I updated the Bootply_ http://bootply.com/dCJM6I7z5V

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those elements that is difficult to style. Normally I would try to just use simple css but in cases like this (if you really must style it) then I would use a plugin.

http://www.bartos.me/heapbox/ is one example.

Comment: Hi Patrick thanks for the response. I actually thought that bootstrap was already doing something along these lines because it isn't displaying the default browser dropdown, but rather a custom version like the examples you've given. I would like to be able to modify the bootstrap one rather than get another one.